# Nativescript ios app with Webpack quit after booting

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript

I have implemented webpack(nativescript-dev-webpack 0.15.1) for my nativescript angular app, on --bundle it works fine in simulator, but when i try to run that same .ipa on my device the app exit after booting. Any help will be appreciated,thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share more information, did you try to debug the application? is there any error code?

Comment: Also, make sure that you have the needed provision profile to deploy on that real device. Run `tns run ios --provision` ... see the available provisions and the deploy with `tns run ios --bundle --provision <my-provision-here>`

Comment: @briosheje, thanks for the comment, as i said no error logs found in simulator's console, fine if its build or deploy or run. The problem occurs when running in device.

Comment: @NickIliev, thanks for the comment, i tried those methods.

Comment: Build the app and open it via XCode (`platforms/ios/<you-project>.xcworkspace`) - from there check the provisions once again and try to run from XCode

Comment: @NickIliev i got this error after open.xcworkspace Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: .., i change that to a valid one in xcode and run in console, it changed automatically in xcode.

Comment: So you are able to sign the app via XCode but not via CLI - is that correct? If that's the case you could log an issue with all the details (including CLI and XCode versions) here https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues

Comment: Make sure that you are using the correct provision when buiolding for device (including development vs production) and also check if the provided provision hasnt expired